# Rails 6 return 500 error without information in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

On my server I get a 500 error in production. I checked the production.log but I have only one error without information:

```
I, [2020-04-21T16:05:31.764482 #1]  INFO -- : [02340258-b640-43e6-811b-18b76867f8ad] Processing by SessionsController#login as HTML
I, [2020-04-21T16:05:31.766391 #1]  INFO -- : [02340258-b640-43e6-811b-18b76867f8ad]   Rendering sessions/login.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2020-04-21T16:05:31.768061 #1]  INFO -- : [02340258-b640-43e6-811b-18b76867f8ad]   Rendered sessions/login.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 309)
I, [2020-04-21T16:05:31.791413 #1]  INFO -- : [02340258-b640-43e6-811b-18b76867f8ad] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5899)
```

My login action has no action code, I only have one simple view file, and every page in my development system works fine but I can't find the real error.

I changed this conf in the production environment:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

But, again, it does not report the full error in production.log.

Also i installed therubyracer gem for get full error message and again not working

My system configuration is:

- Rails version: `gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'`
- Ruby version: `ruby:2.6.1`

Comment: 500 means it's an 'internal server error'.  Probably a syntax error.  Does it run on development?

Comment: "Server error" could mean just about anything. Does `rails c` work on your production instance? If not you'll usually get a stack trace and a place to start looking.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to write using proper grammar. SO is not a message board or forum, it's much more like an online reference book, where grammar matters. Capitalization helps readability, and putting in the time to write correctly shows us you cared enough to try. "[ask]" and the linked pages talk about this.

Comment: @Thomas i dont have syntax error also every controller in development(local system) works fine

Comment: @tadman yes rails console works fine in production and development mode

Comment: @mohammadmahmoodi It might not be so much a syntax error but the code for your action probably isn't doing what you think it is.  Look at what you expect to happen, and re-evaulate the logic for that action.  It's hard to debug an issue when you don't provide the information about the project.  An internal server error just means that something didn't go right on the server side, and it essentially doesn't know what exactly...

Comment: @Thomas i posted this issues in github/rails and they approved my issues and fixed on next update (Problem is on webpacker when webpacker not installed on production server returning this error) , can u posts this answer (with No spelling mistakes :))) )